# Why isn't my package showing up on a privately hosted Cydia repo?

Tags: cydia

I followed the steps outlined [this guide](http://www.saurik.com/id/7).  But for some reason Cydia isn't showing the package when I browse the repo.  The repo address is chrisrjones.com/repo  I can add the repo is Cydia, but the package in the repo is not showing up / displaying in the repo when I browse it.

Comment: Added your repo - KegCop app shows up.

Comment: Yeah apparently, the previous package I had installed was conflicting with the repo version.  So now I removed the local version from device, readded repo, and I see the app.  However it fails to install :(

Comment: Your comment helped me just now, setting up a Cydia repo for this first time. Did you ever get your repo working?

Comment: @newenglander glad I could help.  Yes I got the repo working, but I eventually released the app in the App Store, so I no longer have a need to host a Cydia repo.